# MS SQL Server: DELETE ... ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `task` as below:

```
CREATE TABLE task (
  "id" AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "name", 
  "user_id",
  "next_task_id",
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_task_next_task_id" FOREIGN KEY ("next_task_id") REFERENCES "task" ("id")
)
```

And the sample data:

```
id  name                   user_id   next_task_id
-------------------------------------------------
1   Cook Pizza             99        NULL
2   Prepare materials      99        1
3   Buy materials          99        2
```

User with id `99` has three tasks: `Buy materials` then `Prepare materials` and then `Cook Pizza` in that sequence.

I want to delete all tasks of user id `99` with a SQL command below:

```
DELETE FROM task 
WHERE user_id = 99
ORDER BY id DESC
```

It works fine in MySQL but **NOT WORK in MS SQL Server**.
MS SQL Server display error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'`

What SQL command can I use to delete tasks of user id `99` in MS SQL Server?

Thanks,

Comment: `order by` makes no sense whatsoever with a `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Why are you trying to apply an `ORDER BY` to this? Just remove it

Comment: Why does the order the rows are deleted in matter?

Comment: The FK isn't revalidated after each individual row is deleted. So long as you're deleting rows and all of their references in the same statement, all is fine, and as others say, no need for `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @MartinSmith 
- On MySQL: without ORDER BY clause  Error 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails'. It works fine with ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting hierarchical data in SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882352/deleting-hierarchical-data-in-sql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order by statement only works with commands that have a data output. Since your command is to delete data, there is no data to order by. And the delete command, as you wrote it, is a set based command, meaning that the whole set will be deleted as a whole instead of a row by row delete.
So the correct syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM [task] 
WHERE user_id = 99
```

Comment: On MySQL: without ORDER BY clause  Error 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails'.

Comment: @Trung Well, that's nice but irrelevant. You are using SQL Server and it does not share that sql syntax.

Comment: @trung Well, MS SQL Server uses Transact SQL, MySQL uses SQL/PSM. Both are unique supersets of SQL Language, based on the ANSI SQL standard. So what works in MySQL will not work in MSSQL, unless it is clean ANSI SQL.

Comment: @Trung - you just need to removed the `ORDER BY` in SQL Server. You don't get the same error as MySQL regarding the FK and the syntax isn't supported. So you will need two different statements if you need to support both DBMS